# Combine solid and dashed border

Tags: html, css

I want to set a border to my block element as the following:

[image]

I.e. I want to set a yellow solid border and black dashed border which located over the yellow solid. How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give your element a yellow border, then use a pseudo element to create the dashed border:

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #666;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z8BSs/

Comment: If the border needs to enclose the entire element rather than just one of its sides, you'll need to change all the offsets to `-1px` (for all of left-right-top-bottom) and (of course) have `border` instead of `border-bottom`.

Comment: @BoltClock - Of course. Was mainly showing what the OP asked. As always, adapt as needed.

Comment: No worries, my comment was more intended to augment your answer for the OP rather than directed at you or saying "you should change your answer!" :)

Comment: For the record, [here's a fiddle showing the border all around](http://jsfiddle.net/z8BSs/1/).

Answer (score 4):

you could use as well `border` + `outline` test this:

```
div {
  margin:5em;
  padding:2em;
  outline:dashed 10px;/* same size as border */
  border:solid yellow 10px ;/* same size as outline */
  outline-offset:-10px;/* negative value as opposite size of border/outline */
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dhlzx

................................................
Another way to use the `box-shadow` would be :

```
    div {
      margin:5em;
      padding:2em;
      border:dashed 10px;
      background:yellow;
      box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2000px white;/* this gives a white background , you may use multiple shadow and resize them in order to
 hide background color that will remain seen behind border dashed, double or dotted*/
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgGke

Comment: +1 Cool use of `outline-offset`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work in IE. Not even IE11 :(

Comment: oh yes , IE11 :), so the box-shadow + background + border would be an average option wich would allow only colors as background like white :   border:dashed 10px;
  background:yellow;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2000px white;  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgGke

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is use box shadows, since you can declare as many as you want. Then use a border for the center dashed line.
here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tetx6/

```
.borders {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 10px yellow,
      inset 0 0 0 10px yellow;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 10px yellow,
      inset 0 0 0 10px yellow;
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 0 10px yellow,
      inset 0 0 0 10px yellow;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 10px yellow,
      inset 0 0 0 10px yellow;

    border:10px dashed black;
}
```

Comment: Not quite there - what you're doing is creating two solid yellow borders and creating a dashed black one between them.

Comment: @BoltClock oops, you're right. Only other way I'd say is to use pseudo elements like the answer above.